# return ObjectResult from API and use Status Code in angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

In my .Net Core API I am returning ObjectResult

```
[HttpGet("[Action]")]
    public ObjectResult GetBList()
    {
        List<PendingListBWise> BList = new List<PendingListBWise>();
        try
        {
            BList = GetBWiseList();
            return StatusCode(202, BList);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, new ResultSet() { Message = ex.Message, StatusCode = 500 });
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
```

Now in my angular component , I want to print message if status code is not 202 . **(Update 1)**

```
 GetBList() {
this.ListLoader = true;
var url = this.baseurl + 'api/GeneratePDF/GetList/';
this.http.get<PendingListBWise[]>(url)
  .toPromise()
  .then(result:HttpResponse<PendingListBWise[]> => {
    this.BList = result;
    this.ListLoader = false;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    this.ListLoader = false;
    console.error(error);
  });
```

}

> Give Compile time error in .then(result:HttpResponse => {
>   } Expected 0-2 arguments but got 3

for getting response code here I have to do

```
.subscribe(result:httpResponse => {
    console.log(result);

  }, error => {
    console.error(error);

  });
```

But that remove casting of result from PendingListBWise[] which means result will not get typed into required class ,

How can I get both data and status code here ?

Comment: You can use the generics, so change it to `result: HttpResponse<PendingListBWise[]>` and get the value with `result.body`

Comment: @user184994 it says that expected 0-2 parameter but got 3

Comment: Which line is giving that error? In your example above the function is only using 2 parameters

Comment: Check Update 1, after get there is <PendingListBWise[]> , although removing it does not help

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, remove the generics from `http.get<PendingListBWise[]>`

Then, move the generics onto the `HttpResponse`.

You should end up with something like:

```
  GetBList() {
    this.ListLoader = true;
    var url = this.baseurl + 'api/GeneratePDF/GetList/';
    this.http.get(url)
      .toPromise()
      .then((result: HttpResponse <PendingListBWise[]>) => {
        this.BList = result;
        this.ListLoader = false;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.ListLoader = false;
        console.error(error);
      }); 
  }
```